# Trying to request a variable before running a curl and read back as integer

Tags: shell-script, curl

```
echo -e "Enter layoutID: \c"
read layoutID
echo -e "Enter playlistID: \c"
read playlistID
echo -e "Enter siteID: \c"
read siteID

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"LayoutId":$LayoutId..... api call.
```

`LayoutId` needs to be a integer and it errors once it hits the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Shell variables are not expanded in single quotes.  Use double quotes and escape all double quotes inside them.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"LayoutId\":$LayoutId..... api call.
```

Or feed your data from stdin using heredoc:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- <<EOF
{"LayoutId":$LayoutId..... api call.
EOF
```